# UI5: Variant persistent using Smart Variant Management

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

My UI5 app resides in SAP Gateway system, I am using SmartVariant management in UI5 to store variants.
I would like to persist the variant details in ABAP backend system not in SAP Gateway system.
Currently variants persist in Gateway system were UI5 app resides.

Is there any way to set a path so lrep calls points to ABAP backend system?

Thanks
Rathish

Answer (score 1):

No. This is a service from the Fiori Launchpad.

Apart from that, that are a number of reasons why that is not a good idea:

- You might have multiple back end systems
- A back end might not even have the Fiori (SAP_UI) component
- Fiori launchpad version in the back end most likely does not match with the version in the front end system.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have deployed my app in UI5 ABAP repository and using it in Enterprise Portal. We do not want to store variants or create TR for variant in Gateway system, so only option left here is to create a custom Odata for variant.